# REST no microframework Inphinit

Tags: php, rest, route, inphinit

A [funcionalidade experimental REST](https://github.com/inphinit/inphinit/wiki/Rest) do microframework Inphinit requer uma classe com 7 funções

- `index`
- `create`
- `store`
- `show`
- `edit`
- `update`
- `destroy`

Numa API REST basicamente são necessários dois *entry points* para o verbo GET, um que irá devolver todos os dados (filtrados ou não, paginados ou não) e um que irá devolver um recurso específico, ou seja, `show` e `index`

Qual a utilidade das funções `create` e `edit`? É possível desabilitar elas?

Comment: É bem provavel que `create` e `edit` siga uma lógica parecida com o do Laravel: criar a camada de visualização, para exibição de formulários.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters me parece estranho, sempre liguei o REST a arquitetura moderna, onde o backend só trafega os dados, ou seja, as telas de formulário de cadastro e alteração não fazem parte da responsabilidade do back

Comment: Concordo com você. Mas o controller é responsável por renderizar a view. Num cenário onde o front-end está no framework, faz sentido ser assim. Agora se você usar o framework apenas para servir REST, realmente, os métodos não fariam sentido. Resta o criador dar uma opção para deixar esses métodos opcionais.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters eles só são adicionados/existem se o Controller tiver os métodos `create()` e `edit()`, se na classe não tiver então seria semelhante a usar `Route::resource('photos', 'Usuarios')->except([ 'create', 'edit' ]);` do Laravel, a diferença é que não precisa executar um except, basta não criar os métodos na classe e o FW se encarrega disto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sou o desenvolvedor deste framework, vamos isolar algumas explicações

> Inphinit requer uma classe com 7 funções

Na verdade não é requerido, todos são opcionais, basicamente a classe `Rest` checa quais métodos da classe são validos em:

```
private static $valids = array(
    'index'   => array( 'GET',  '/' ),
    'create'  => array( 'GET',  '/create' ),
    'store'   => array( 'POST', '/' ),
    'show'    => array( 'GET',  '/{:[^/]+:}' ),
    'edit'    => array( 'GET',  '/{:[^/]+:}/edit' ),
    'update'  => array( array('PUT', 'PATCH'), '/{:[^/]+:}' ),
    'destroy' => array( 'DELETE', '/{:[^/]+:}' ),
);
```

E depois comparando ao que você setou:

```
$route = empty(self::$valids[$method]) ? false : self::$valids[$method];
```

A classe `Rest` é apenas **um facilitador**, ela cria as rotas conforme você configura a classe do seu controller

> É possível desabilitar elas?

Sim, são opcionais

Tanto é um facilitador que sem ele você poderia criar a sua API manualmente (se assim deseja-se), por exemplo **com sessões** para simular a gravação e leitura de dados:

```
<?php

use Inphinit\Routing\Route;
use Inphinit\Http\Request;
use Inphinit\Http\Response;

session_start();

// Cria os dados iniciais se não existirem `Inphinit\Experimental\Rest`
if (empty($_SESSION['exemplo'])) {
    $_SESSION['exemplo'] = array(
        array( 'id' => 1, 'name' => 'Guilherme Costamilam' ),
        array( 'id' => 2, 'name' => 'Wallace Maxters' ),
        array( 'id' => 3, 'name' => 'Carlos Bacco' )
    );
}

function getItemById($id)
{
    foreach ($_SESSION['exemplo'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['id'] == $id) return $key;
    }

    return false;
}

// Lista todas "entidades"
Route::set('GET', '/api/', function () {
    Response::type('application/json');

    return json_encode($_SESSION['exemplo']);
});

// Adiciona uma nova "entidade"
Route::set('POST', '/api/', function () {
    $raw = stream_get_contents( Request::raw() );
    $json = null;

    if ($raw) {
        $json = json_decode($raw);
    }

    //Pega a ultima ID
    $lastId = max(array_column($_SESSION['exemplo'], 'id'));

    //Nova ID
    $newId = ++$lastId;

    if (empty($json->name)) {
        $status = 400;
        $response = array( 'response' => 'Dados inválidos' );
    } else {
        $_SESSION['exemplo'][] = array(
            'id' => $newId,
            'name' => $json->name
        );

        $status = 201;
        $response = array( 'response' => true );
    }

    Response::status($status);
    Response::type('application/json');

    return json_encode($response);
});

// Lê uma entidade especifica
Route::set('GET', '/api/{:\d+:}', function ($id) {
    Response::type('application/json');

    $key = getItemById($id);

    if (empty($_SESSION['exemplo'][$key])) {
        Response::status(404);
        $response = array( 'response' => 'Não encontrado' );
    } else {
        $response = $_SESSION['exemplo'][$key];
    }

    return json_encode($response);
});

// Deleta uma entidade especifica
Route::set('DELETE', '/api/{:\d+:}', function ($id) {
    Response::type('application/json');

    $key = getItemById($id);

    if (empty($_SESSION['exemplo'][$key])) {
        Response::status(404);
        $response = array( 'response' => 'Não encontrado' );
    } else {
        unset($_SESSION['exemplo'][$key]);

        $response = array( 'response' => true );
    }

    return json_encode($response);
});
```

Isso seria um exemplo de uma API bem básica, claro que tudo feito "manualmente", agora criando um controlador e usado a classe `Inphinit\Experimental\Rest` ficaria algo assim:

- `./system/main.php`

  ```
  <?php

  use Inphinit\Experimental\Routing\Rest;

  Rest::create('Photo');
  ```
- `./system/application/Controller/Pessoas.php`

  ```
  <?php
  namespace Controller;

  use Inphinit\Response;

  class Pessoas
  {
      //Ao instanciar a classe (ocorre internamente dentro de )
      public function __construct()
      {
          session_start();

          // Cria os dados iniciais se não existirem
          if (empty($_SESSION['exemplo'])) {
              $_SESSION['exemplo'] = array(
                  array( 'id' => 1, 'name' => 'Guilherme Costamilam' ),
                  array( 'id' => 2, 'name' => 'Wallace Maxters' ),
                  array( 'id' => 3, 'name' => 'Carlos Bacco' )
              );
          }
      }

      // acesse via GET http://site.com/
      public function index()
      {
          return json_encode($_SESSION['exemplo']);
      }

      // acesse via POST http://site.com/
      public function store()
      {
          $raw = Request::raw();
          $json = null;

          if ($raw) {
              $json = json_decode($raw);
          }

          if (empty($json->name)) {
              $status = 400;
              $response = array( 'response' => 'Dados inválidos' );
          } else {
              $status = 201;
              $response = array( 'response' => true );
          }

          Response::status($status);
          Response::type('application/json');

          return json_encode($response);
      }

      // acesse via GET http://site.com/show/<ID>
      public function show($id)
      {
          $key = getItemById($id);

          if (empty($_SESSION['exemplo'][$key])) {
              Response::status(404);
              $response = array( 'response' => 'Não encontrado' );
          } else {
              $response = $_SESSION['exemplo'][$id];
          }

          return json_encode($response);
      }

      // acesse via DELETE http://site.com/<ID>
      public function destroy($id)
      {
          $key = getItemById($id);

          if (empty($_SESSION['exemplo'][$key])) {
              Response::status(404);
              $response = array( 'response' => 'Não encontrado' );
          } else {
              unset($_SESSION['exemplo'][$key]);

              $response = array( 'response' => true );
          }

          return json_encode($response);
      }

      private function getItemById($id)
      {
          foreach ($_SESSION['exemplo'] as $key => $value) {
              if ($value['id'] == $id) return $key;
          }

          return false;
      }
  }
  ```

---

Essa explicação toda foi para entender o que pode "facilitar", agora vamos a explicação dos metódos especificos `create` e `edit`, pessoalmente creio que estes métodos sejam necessários somente em ambientes como páginas web ou que irá renderizar algo como formulários HTML.

Por exemplo nestes métodos teriam formulários que fariam requisições `fetch()` ou `XmlHttpRequest` que acessariam os metodos `store` e `update`.

Agora outro cenário, imagine que você esta criando uma aplicação JavaFX, e deseja usar FXML (leia https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html), então o `create`:

```
public function create($id)
{
    Response::type('application/xml');

    return '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <?import java.net.*?>
        <?import javafx.geometry.*?>
        <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
        <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
        <?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

        <GridPane fx:controller="fxmlexample.FXMLExampleController" 
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10"
            styleClass="root">
            <padding><Insets top="25" right="25" bottom="25" left="25"/></padding>

            <Label text="Digite o nome do novo usuário:"
                GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>

            <TextField 
                GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>

            <HBox spacing="10" alignment="bottom_right" 
                GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                <Button text="Sign In"     
                onAction="#handleSubmitButtonAction"/>
            </HBox>

        </GridPane>';
}
```

E no `edit` retornariam algo como:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    Response::type('application/xml');

    $name = null;

    foreach ($_SESSION['foobarbaz'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['id'] == $id) {
            $name = $value['name'];
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!$name) {
        Response::status(404);
        $response = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
            <Label text="Não encontrado!"/>';
    } else {
        $response = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <?import java.net.*?>
            <?import javafx.geometry.*?>
            <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
            <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
            <?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

            <GridPane fx:controller="fxmlexample.FXMLExampleController" 
                xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10"
                styleClass="root">
                <padding><Insets top="25" right="25" bottom="25" left="25"/></padding>

                <Label text="Edite o nome do usuário:"
                    GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>

                <TextField text="' . $name . '"
                    GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>

                <HBox spacing="10" alignment="bottom_right" 
                    GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                    <Button text="Sign In"     
                    onAction="#handleSubmitButtonAction"/>
                </HBox>

            </GridPane>';
    }

    return $response;
}
```

> Se tiver alguma falha nos FXMLs me informe, não é minha área

São exemplos hipotéticos apenas, muitas coisas me basiei em frameworks existentes para facilitar as pessoas se adaptarem e aprenderem rápido o uso do framework, tentando deixar um pouco mais fácil

Devo deixar algo claro sobre o namespace `Inphinit\Experimental`, tudo que estiver nele é voltado a sugestões (não que os demais não aceitem), aceito qualquer sugestão e vou analisar com calma, mas para resumir se tiverem sugestões de como trabalhar com REST no framework podem entrar em contato comigo por onde desejar, facebook, telegram e linkedin.

Para resumir, se deseja somente uma API com JSON ou Xml você apenas criar os métodos assim:

```
class Usuarios
{
    // acesse via GET http://site/photo/
    public function index()
    {
        ...
    }

    // acesse via GET http://site/photo/create
    public function create()
    {
        ...
    }

    // acesse via POST http://site/photo/
    public function store()
    {
        ...
    }

    // acesse via GET http://site/photo/show/<digite o nome ou ID>
    public function show($id)
    {
        ...
    }

    // acesse via PUT http://site/photo/<digite o nome ou ID>
    public function update($id)
    {
        ...
    }

    // acesse via DELETE http://site/photo/<digite o nome ou ID>
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Desta forma as rotas `GET /create` e `GET /<id ou algo assim>/edit` **não** estarão disponíveis

---

### Extra: Agrupar rotas

Você pode isolar a API por uma "sub-rota" com `Inphinit\Experimental\Group` algo como:

```
<?php
use Inphinit\Experimental\Routing\Rest;
use Inphinit\Experimental\Routing\Group;

Group::create()->path('/api/')->then(function () {
    Rest::create('Usuarios');
});
```

Pode isolar por domínios:

```
//Acessivel via foobar.com ou www.foobar.com
Group::create()->domain('{:www|:}.foobar.com')->then(function () {
    Route::set('GET', '/', 'Foo:index');
    Route::set('GET', '/abc', 'Foo:bar');
    Route::set('GET', '/xyz/', 'Foo:baz');
});

//Acessivel via api.foobar.com
Group::create()->domain('api.foobar.com')->then(function () {
    Rest::create('Usuarios');
});
```

O que seria outra forma de isolar o que são formulários e afins e isolar o que são APIs

Comment: Legal, minha única sugestão seria usar um nome como *resource* ao invés de REST. Uma pergunta, caso então eu tente acessar uma rota que não defini, o que retorna? 404?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam sim, 404, mas ando pensando em mudar o esquema para rotas registradas mas com métodos diferentes para `405 Method Not Allowed`, isso para qualquer rota, seja em um site normal, seja em uma API

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam pela lógica de como implementei o sistema de API realmente seria sobre um "RESOURCE" por vez, no entanto a ideia de escrever REST inicialmente me pareceu mais intuitiva para os usuários entenderem o uso indicado, claro que o FW ali permite você meio que usar como desejar, não sou muito fã de limitar as pessoas, mas vou pensar bem e sugerir algo para vê se agrada. Tenho algumas melhorias para a versão 0.1.3 (ou 0.2.0) que ainda preciso publicar, nada que afete o funcionamento :)

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam adiantei o que foi possivel, versão 0.1.5, agora rotas definidas, mas em métodos diferentes do acessado irão emitir o código 405, a classe `Inphinit\Experimental\Dom` foi melhorada, ela pode ser uma boa para devolver arrays como JSON ou como XML variando conforme o cabeçalho `Accepts` do HTTP (aproveite de dê uma lida em https://github.com/inphinit/inphinit/wiki/Negociação-de-Conteúdo-HTTP e https://github.com/inphinit/inphinit/wiki/DOM%2C-Xml%2C-HTML%2C-Json-e-Arrays#array-para-dom-xml-ou-html)

Comment: Realmente fiquei na dúvida em relação ao 404 vs 405 (da pra fazer uma pergunta). Valeu pela ajuda e parabéns pelo Inphinit

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam acho legal a ideia, dá para responder algo bem legal, para adiantar 405 é quando a rota "existe" mas o método HTTP esperado é outro, na lógica inicial do FW eu tinha criado que as rotas com verbos (GET, POST, etc) eram diferentes, por exemplo `GET /foo` e `POST /foo` seriam coisas diferentes, mas com a resposta 405 dá para facilitar o entendimento de que existe, acaso quem vá usar a API configure errado o programa cliente, me adicione no telegram, quero te mandar alguns links